# Express Has No Method 'uid'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am currently creating a todo list app and express gives me this error when I run `app.js`.

Express

```
500 TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'uid'
at Object.exports.current_user [as handle] (C:\Users\steph_000\SkyDrive\Documents\Programs\Todo List App\todo\routes\index.js:95:34)
at next (C:\Users\steph_000\SkyDrive\Documents\Programs\Todo List App\todo\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15)
at Object.methodOverride [as handle] (C:\Users\steph_000\SkyDrive\Documents\Programs\Todo List App\todo\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\methodOverride.js:48:5)
at next (C:\Users\steph_000\SkyDrive\Documents\Programs\Todo List App\todo\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15)
at Object.urlencoded [as handle] (C:\Users\steph_000\SkyDrive\Documents\Programs\Todo List App\todo\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\urlencoded.js:41:37)
at next (C:\Users\steph_000\SkyDrive\Documents\Programs\Todo List App\todo\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15)
at Object.json [as handle] (C:\Users\steph_000\SkyDrive\Documents\Programs\Todo List App\todo\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\json.js:42:37)
at next (C:\Users\steph_000\SkyDrive\Documents\Programs\Todo List App\todo\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15)
at multipart (C:\Users\steph_000\SkyDrive\Documents\Programs\Todo List App\todo\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\multipart.js:97:37)
at C:\Users\steph_000\SkyDrive\Documents\Programs\Todo List App\todo\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\bodyParser.js:64:9
```

Also, the script is

```
var utils    = require( 'util' );
var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' );
var Todo     = mongoose.model( 'Todo' );

exports.index = function ( req, res, next ){
  var user_id = req.cookies ?
    req.cookies.user_id : undefined;

  Todo.
    find({ user_id : user_id }).
    sort( '-updated_at' ).
    exec( function ( err, todos ){
      if( err ) return next( err );

      res.render( 'index', {
          title : 'Express Todo Example',
          todos : todos
      });
    });
};

exports.create = function ( req, res, next ){
  new Todo({
      user_id    : req.cookies.user_id,
      content    : req.body.content,
      updated_at : Date.now()
  }).save( function ( err, todo, count ){
    if( err ) return next( err );

    res.redirect( '/' );
  });
};

exports.destroy = function ( req, res, next ){
  Todo.findById( req.params.id, function ( err, todo ){
    var user_id = req.cookies ?
      req.cookies.user_id : undefined;

    if( todo.user_id !== req.cookies.user_id ){
      return utils.forbidden( res );
    }

    todo.remove( function ( err, todo ){
      if( err ) return next( err );

      res.redirect( '/' );
    });
  });
};

exports.edit = function( req, res, next ){
  var user_id = req.cookies ?
      req.cookies.user_id : undefined;

  Todo.
    find({ user_id : user_id }).
    sort( '-updated_at' ).
    exec( function ( err, todos ){
      if( err ) return next( err );

      res.render( 'edit', {
        title   : 'Express Todo Example',
        todos   : todos,
        current : req.params.id
      });
    });
};

exports.update = function( req, res, next ){
  Todo.findById( req.params.id, function ( err, todo ){
    var user_id = req.cookies ?
      req.cookies.user_id : undefined;

    if( todo.user_id !== user_id ){
      return utils.forbidden( res );
    }

    todo.content    = req.body.content;
    todo.updated_at = Date.now();
    todo.save( function ( err, todo, count ){
      if( err ) return next( err );

      res.redirect( '/' );
    });
  });
};

// ** express turns the cookie key to lowercase **
exports.current_user = function ( req, res, next ){
  var user_id = req.cookies ?
      req.cookies.user_id : undefined;

  if( !user_id ){
    res.cookie( 'user_id', utils.uid( 32 ));
  }

  next();
};
```

Help! I can't figure this out as I have searched all over the internet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the error is occurring on line no. 95 of given file i.e.

```
res.cookie( 'user_id', utils.uid( 32 ));
```

It says the the module `util` which you are importing through `require( 'util' )` does not contains `uid` method

You can also check the documentation of `util` [here](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html)

The `util` module does not have `uid` method.

If you want to generate `uid` you can make use of libraries like `node-uuid`
https://github.com/broofa/node-uuid

Comment: Yes... I have just noticed that.

Comment: Is there a way to install github projects on node?

Comment: Sorry... I am kind of new to node :P

Comment: Never Mind I Figured It Out!

Comment: Node has package manager called `npm`. It will get installed along with node. For more information on `npm` please refer https://docs.npmjs.com/